# "To be or not to be" permutations

Tags: combinatorics

The question is, how many ways to rearrange letters of "to be or not to be that is the question" so, that we would get:

- 1 8-letter word
- 1 4-letter word
- 2 3-letter words
- 6 2-letter words

Words can be in any order, and of course doesnt have to mean anything. ie "ot eb ro question to be that is not the" is suitable variant.

I figure that first step would be to count all permutations of string(len 39) - $39!$

Then

- space  count  9
- t  count  7
- o  count  5
- b  count  2
- e  count  4
- r  count  1
- n  count  2
- h  count  2
- a  count  1
- i  count  2
- q  count  1
- u  count  1
- s  count  2

And since letters can actually be in any order(lets forget spaces) -
$39!/(7!5!2!4!1!2!2!1!2!1!1!2!)=39!/(7!5!2!4!2!2!2!2!)$

But spaces puzzle me, those can be in any order, but there is restriction of not putting space as a first letter, as a last letter and no doublespaces.

How to formalize those restrictions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count permutations of the *letters* separately, ignoring where the spaces are, and then multiply with the number of permutations of the *word lengths* multiset $\{2,2,2,3,2,2,4,2,3,8\}$.